# Extend Component decorator

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular **7.1.4**

```
@FieldComponent({
  templateUrl: './field-phone.component.html',
  selector: 'app-field-phone'
})
export class FieldPhone {
}
```

and the decorator itself

```
export function FieldComponent(metadata: Component) {
  return function(target: function) {
    return Component(metadata)(target);
  }
}
```

the result: `zone.js:665 Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load field-phone.component.html ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load field-phone.component.html`

This is the way I was trying to extend the native angular Component decorator but still can't get it work. How to properly extend the decorator?

Comment: Is the path to the `templateUrl` correct?

Comment: Well, actually they were correct but it seems like during the new decorator building I lost the context and path like ``./xxxx`` doesn't work anymore.

Comment: It seems to work for me (see [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vcgvum?file=src%2Fapp%2Ffieldcomponent.decorator.ts)). If you think that the context is lost, you may try returning an arrow function: `return (target: any) => { ... }`.

Comment: Yeah, I tried everything but still the same error. Do you think that running the app locally has something to do with this? The error message is now ``zone.js:2969 GET http://localhost:4200/field-phone.component.html 404 (Not Found)``

Comment: @ConnorsFan what's interesting it's that if I log out metadata on your demo I'll get already built html and css code. When I log it out in my local code I still have plain urls in my metadata object.